# Correct methods in Ruby on Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

My Rails model has some bad lines. In general, first error is when accessing `roles` variable from `has_access` def. And then, second is when making `where` action.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations_users
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { minimum: 4, maximum: 35 }, uniqueness: true
  roles = { :administrator => 1, :support => 2 }

  def has_access(chosen_user, role)
      self.organizations_users.where('user_id = ? and role = ?', chosen_user.id, roles[role]).exists?
  end

  def add_user(chosen_user, role)
      if !self.has_access(chosen_user, role)
          self.organizations_users.create({user_id: chosen_user.id, role: roles[role]})
      end
      has_access(chosen_user,role)
  end

end
```

I need also to query over `organizations_users` table to get information about access. How can I fix that?

Comment: ... What's the error?

Comment: For where statement (2nd) is "undefined method `where' for #<Organization:0x4892898>". For roles is undefined local variable or method `roles' for #<Organization:0x47b0038>

Comment: What do you want to do? Explain what do you expect this method to do.

Comment: I need to have method which will be accessible both within a class and on instance. I want those methods to return does user have access to organization and to add user to organization.

Comment: Can't you turn that has_access into a scope? Then you would reference it as `!Organization.has_access(chosen_user, role)`

Comment: Something like `scope :has_access, lambda { |chosen_user, role| #something something....  }`

Comment: If you do User.first.method you always generating an instance of the user and has_access will work.

Comment: Edit the question to explain what are you trying to do, this fails and pasting a piece of code is not enough to solve a question that changes on each solution.

Comment: You want add_user to find the entry in the user_organizations table, or create one if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

To find or add the organization do:

```
def has_access(role)
  self.organizations_user.find_or_create_by_role(role)
end
```

This allow you to use:

```
user = User.has_access("administrator")

user = User.first.has_acess("administrator")
```

And will do a find in the table user_organizations or create a new entry if can't find one. ActiveRecord relation will take care of the user_id

Comment: But then it is not accessible like `user_access = User.first.has_access...`

Comment: That's because User.first is returning a single instance, and then you are trying to do a .where which is a Class method for arrays.

Comment: However, this self. doesn't work, tried it now. I need to have method which will be accessible both within a class and on instance

Comment: `def self.*` makes Organization.* class method. Think static methods in a statically compiled language. You cannot call self.*, you would have to call Organization.*

Comment: Try this as long as has access is a boolean.

Comment: Again mistake, I need to make a join on has_and_belongs_to_many table is has_access method.

Comment: What about this one, is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix would be to change

```
def has_access(chosen_user, role)
  where('user_id = ? and role = ?', chosen_user.id, roles[role]).exists?
end
```

to:

```
def has_access(chosen_user, role)
  Organization.where('user_id = ? and role = ?', chosen_user.id, roles[role]).exists?
end
```

The reason for this is the where() method is a class method and only accessible from the class itself, IE. `Organization.where`.  BTW, I am assuming (dangerously :) ) That this where clause is used from Organization.